# ajax based multiple dropdown showing result with pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

have 3 drop-down

`select#opt-category,select#opt-sector,select#opt-company`

category onchange

```
$("select#opt-category").change(function () {
    category = $(this).val();
    if(sector!='')sector='';
    if(company!='')company='';
    $("#opt-sector").load('menus.php?category='+category);
    $("#opt-company").load('menucmp.php?category='+category);
});
```

will load sector and company based on category and result shown as

```
$(".showgrid").load('portal.php?category='+category+'&sector='+sector+'&company='+company);
```

the results are based on paging which also called ajax

```
              function loading_show(){
                $('#loading').html("<img src='assets/img/ajax-loader.gif'/>").fadeIn('slow');
            }
            function loading_hide(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut('slow');
            }                
            function loadData(page,category){
                loading_show(); 

                $.ajax
                ({

                    type: "POST",

                    url: "pagination_data.php",
                    data: {'page':page,'category':category},

                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#container").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }


        loadData(1,<?php echo $catgory?> )                // For first time page load default results
            $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                var category= $(this).attr('q');
                loadData(page,category);

            });           
            $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var category = parseInt($('.total').attr('b'));

                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page,category);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    //$('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            });
```

when category dropdown changed, it loads the new value on other dropdown but can't load the result into `.showgrid`.

is there another way to accomplished this task

Comment: What is the response from the server to the `portal.php` request (FireBug or the like, or try the full URL in a new tab, what happens then is important)? Are the GET parameters of this request well filled (i.e. where, when and how are you variables filled)? May we see the HTML structure you're applying this JS on (where is .showgrid)? Is the order of the requests really the same as what you explain (you post separate codes, although they must be part of the same script)?

Comment: Actually, to make the long story short: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)